# Divide strings by length of two

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm new to java so I hope you can help me:

I have a string which I'm trying to divide into elements of two. I'm trying to use substring but so far it is not working. Here is what I've tried:

```
public class StreamCipher {

     String first = "315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5b403b510d0d0455468aeb98622b137dae857553ccd8883a7bc37520e06e515d22c954eba5025b8cc";

     public void stringToList() {
          List<String> xorList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (int i = 0; i <= first.length(); i+=2) {
                   String subXOR = first.substring(i, i+2);
                   xorList.add(subXOR);
              }
           }
           System.out.println(xorList);
     }
```

Nevertheless, this error keeps showing up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 174
```

on this line:

```
String subXOR = first.substring(i, i+2);
```

What is wrong?

Comment: change `i <= first.length()` to `i < first.length() - 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= first.length(); i+=2) {
```

With using `<` instead of `<=`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < first.length(); i+=2) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. I just didn't see it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem from what am looking at is that the statement `first.substring(i, i+2);` is executed even when i equals the length of the length of the string

So what you should probably do is

```
public void stringToList() {
          List<String> xorList = new ArrayList<String>();
          for (int i = 0; i <= first.length(); i+=2) {
                   if((i+2)<first.length()){
                   String subXOR = first.substring(i, i+2);
                   xorList.add(subXOR);
                 }
              }
           }
           System.out.println(xorList);
     }
```

This way you are sure that the value of i+2 is always less that the length of the string literal

Comment: Try to correct second :  first.lenght()  to  first.length()